# Last Known Good Configuration is Missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

As the title states I can't find the LKGC. Pressing F8 takes me to a blue screen with all the options (1-9) but no LKGC. I'm using W10 21H2 x64. (19041)

Thanks for any enlightenment,
clyde

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This feature was disabled about 6-8 months ago, since it was disabled, you can reenable it but that won’t help if Windows won’t boot. This is linked to the fact Windows doesn’t automatically backup the registry hive anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck on this. The new Windows 10 Startup Settings screen doesn't have such an option and there is no way to do it.

(There is obviously ways to attempt to fix a Windows that doesn't start properly but that'd depend on what's the issue/error and how it happened. Maybe you can ask another question on that with all the details of the issue you're having.)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8/10/11 have replaced the Last Known Good Configuration with
Safe Mode, so this option has become superfluous and was removed.

For entering Safe mode, see the article
[How to start Windows 11 in Safe Mode (8 ways)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/windows-11-safe-mode/).

A method that used to work but is not listed, so needs testing, is
to turn off the computer and turn it on again, then on the
manufacturer's logo screen, long-press the power button.
Repeating this process several times might be required.
For more details on this method see
[How to boot Last Known Good Configuration on Windows 10, 11](https://www.diskinternals.com/partition-recovery/last-known-good-configuration-on-windows10/).

Comment: Windows 7 also had Safe Mode. LKGC was something else.

Comment: @YisroelTech: Yes, they were both distinct in Windows 7, and LKGC was very useful.

Comment: Then what do you mean by *"**have replaced** the Last Known Good Configuration with Safe Mode"* if Safe Mode was there all along and LKGC was something else?

Comment: @YisroelTech: Both have been merged into Safe mode, but I don't know the details. The LKCG folder of `C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack` still exists and is updated, so hopefully still serves for some purpose.